# How to see the actual query executed by an Oracle report containing an error

Tags: oracle, report, ora-00933

Like most Oracle Reports in O*Financials, the query is made up of dynamic parts depending on the parameters entered.

When I run the concurrent request the log file contains an obscure error:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
                        d.acctd_amount_dr,  d.amount_dr) )  C_AMOUNT , trx . trx_number C_TRX_NUMBER FROM ar_cash_receipt_history crh , ar_distributions d , gl_code_combinations gc , ar_batches b , ar_cash_receipts cr , hz_cust_accounts cust_acct , h

(I don't know why it puts spaces in between the trx.trx_number which is one of my changes.)

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Oracle Reports itself. But what always works to see which sql statements are being sent from a client to an Oracle db, is a sql*net trace. For instructions about how to configure sql*net to create a trace file, please consult the Oracle sql*net documentation or take a look at the [OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Net_FAQ#I_have_some_trouble_with_SQL.2ANet._How_does_one_produce_a_trace_file.3F).

And please, don't forget to deactivate the tracing feature again after you are done with that sql statement.

Comment: If a trace can be done then this would be the best idea. On the other hand, if the report is being run from a reports server it may be difficult to get a trace on exactly the session that is failing. In which case, Steve, you might need to try to reproduce the SQL that the report is running by inspecting the code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.

I copied the query text and concatenated in all the parameters like &LP_ORDER_BY and then displayed it with an SRW_MESSAGE in the BEFORE_REPORT trigger.
Bit tedious, they should have some available field that holds the query.